Glass is not working in 4.2 EEVEE
I have trouble dealing with glass in Blender 4.2. I followed a video about Eevee glass to the tea but still got this result.


Since Blender 4.2, to create glass:

In the Render panel activate Raytracing
In the Material panel > Settings > Surface > activate Raytraced Transmission and for a cube choose Thickness > Slab

